# Inductive proof of swapping rows in an determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$ be an n x n matrix. And let B be such that it is equal A with swapped row i and j. ($1\leq i<j\leq n$)

Using the definition of the determinant iterating through the first column (and no other row operations) prove that:
$\det(B)=-\det(A)$

The definition of a determinant being:
$$\det(A)=\Sigma_{l=0}^n a_{l1}(-1)^{l+1}\det(M_{l1}(A))$$

$M_{l1}(A)$ being A with row $l$ and column  $1$ removed.

Going to the proof:

The principle step, has a trivial solutions and can be shown with 2x2 matrices.
[image]

Going further assuming that the equality holds for (k-1)x(k-1) matrices we look at kxk matrices. 
Looking at 
$$\det(B)=\Sigma_{l=0}^k b_{l1}(-1)^{l+1}\det(M_{l1}(B))$$

[image]

one easily see that in any case where $l\neq i$ or $l\neq j$ that the assumption will give:
$$b_{l1}(-1)^{l+1}\det(M_{l1}(B))=a_{l1}(-1)^{l+1}(-1\det(M_{l1}(A))$$
$\det(M_{l1}(B))=-\det(M_{l1}(A))$ as they both are (k-1)x(k-1), $M_{l1}(B)$ being equal to $M_{l1}(A)$ except for having two rows swapped. 
So it holds for these cases.

Being left with: 
[image]

Where one then can observe if $i$ and $j$ both are even or both are odd, one will in the M determinants get a odd distance between them, where one then can use the assumption and swap back. Swapping and odd amount of times reversing the sign. 
 [image]
[image]

But how do you prove it when $i$ and $j$ have different parity?

(I am aware that there are other ways of proving this, but want to be able to use induction (which I also know works) but am as can bee seen a little stuck)

Comment: Is cofactor expansion necessary ?